# facebook SDK3.1 and Xcode 4.5 linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have a previous project thats using Facebook SDK 3.0 (for iOS 5). and I just updated my xcode to 4.5 (iOS6) and compiler is giving me linker errors. so I delete the facebook (3.0) and add 3.1 but still dont work. does anyone have clue how to fix it?

thanks so much!!

Comment: u might have missed some frameworks.. have u saw the sample code from Facebook, which all frameworks do they import..?

Comment: and also in target build phases some files/resources might not be added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to add the new Frameworks. Try going through this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/